# Can Visual Studio Online CI build to custom host?

Tags: azure, tfs, web-deployment

We're currently using www.visualstudio.com online TFS for our project management and CI deployments to Azure.

However we discovered that some of our basic sites are costing us $10+ a month (Azure charges $9.99 for a shared host with custom domain).

This has us wondering if it is possible to use a host like HostGator, GoDaddy, etc to deploy to using our CI build in TFS?

We would ideally like to still commit into our TFS repository and have the deployment to the custom host be automated as it is with Azure currently.

Tried googling custom build definitions with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS Builds can be customized to do almost anything you can imagine.  Microsoft has provided pre-built templates to deploy to Azure, if you want to deploy elsewhere you will have to do the customization yourself.

You can read about customizing TFS Builds from the ALM Ranger Build Guidance on CodePlex: http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/